# How can I use SSRS to filter just on month when the date is in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to ignore the year and date... For example if 2018-09-08 and 2016-09-04 exist for two different personID, I want both rows of date to come up if I filtered the month to "september"

Comment: What value type are the dates stored in the database as?  Are they Datetimes?  Nvarchars?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this in the dataset filter properties rather than in your dataset query and also assuming you have a report parameter called `@pMonth` then you can add a filter to the dataset.

Set the filter expression to `=Month(Fields!myDateColumn.Value)` and the value expression to `=Parameters!pMonth.Value`

If you wanted to only ever show the records that match the parameter then it's best to do this in the dataset query, that way you only return what you need rather than return lots of data that never gets used.

To do this in SQL Server you would do something similar...

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable t 
    WHERE MONTH(t.myDateColumn) = @pMonth
```